# Remove value and count others in a comma separated list in a dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following example df:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Sara',  'John', 'Christine'],

                   'trip1 places': [np.nan , 4, 0],
                   'trip2 places': [1, 6, 2],
                   'trip3 places': [2, 0, 2],
                   'trip4 places': [2, 2, 2]})

df1
```

looks like:

```
    name    trip1 places    trip2 places    trip3 places    trip4 places
0   Sara       NaN               1               2               2
1   John       4.0               6               0               2
2   Christine  0.0               2               2               2
```

What I am trying to do is find the number of effective trips for trips1 places, trip3 places and trip4 places. This means that values equal 0 should be removed and count the number of other values.

My Approach is to add all the target values to a list and remove the 0 values then count the list items.

```
df1.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Then add the trips of interest in a list:

```
df1['trips'] = df1[['trip1 places','trip3 places','trip4 places']].values.tolist()
```

It gives:

```
    name    trip1 places    trip2 places    trip3 places    trip4 places    trips
0   Sara        0.0             1              2                2   [0.0, 2.0, 2.0]
1   John        4.0             6              0                2   [4.0, 0.0, 2.0]
2   Christine   0.0             2              2                2   [0.0, 2.0, 2.0]
```

Now I need to remove 0.0 from each list and count the other items. Please note that 0.0 could be repeated in other rows.

I tried to add a mask then use `len` to count the items but it fails!

```
m = [element for element in df1['trips'] if element != 0]
```

Expected output:

```
    name    trip1 places    trip2 places    trip3 places    trip4 places    effective trips     # effective trips
0   Sara          0.0            1               2             2                [0.0, 2.0, 2.0]     2
1   John          4.0            6              0              2                [4.0, 0.0, 2.0]     2
2   Christine     0.0            2              2              2                [0.0, 2.0, 2.0]     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `stack` , after get the list then do the `str.len`

```
df1['new list'] = df1[['trip1 places','trip3 places','trip4 places']].stack().loc[lambda x : x!=0].groupby(level=0).agg(list)
Out[166]: 
0    [2.0, 2.0]
1    [4.0, 2.0]
2    [2.0, 2.0]
dtype: object


df['off trips'] = df1['new list'].str.len()

Out[167]: 
0    2
1    2
2    2
dtype: int64
```